# angular2 print json from service

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I don't know how to get the data from JSON printed in my template

if i use in template:
template: `people: {{people}}` or template: `people: {{articles}}`
always get in the browser:

> people: [object Object]

if i use in template:
template: `people: {{people.totalrecords}}` or template: `people: {{articlestotalrecords}}`

in get blank value:
people:

```js
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {Component, enableProdMode, Injectable, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS, URLSearchParams} from 'angular2/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {enableProdMode} from 'angular2/core';

@Injectable()
class ArticleApi {
  constructor(private http: Http) {}
  getData: string;

  seachArticle(query) {
    const endpoint = 'http://xdemocrm.com/webservicecrm.php';
    const searchParams = new URLSearchParams()
    searchParams.set('object', 'account');
    searchParams.set('action', 'list');   
    return this.http
      .get(endpoint, {search: searchParams})
      .map(res => res.json())
  }

  postExample(someData) {
    return this.http
      .post('https://yourEndpoint', JSON.stringify(someData))
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `people: {{people}}`, 
  providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS, ArticleApi],
})
class App implements OnInit {
  public people;
  constructor(private articleApi: ArticleApi) { }
  public articles: Array<any> = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.articles = this.articleApi.seachArticle('obama')
        .subscribe (data => this.people = data) 
  }
}

bootstrap(App)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>angular2 http exmaple</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js"></script>
  <script src="config.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/Rx.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/angular2.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/http.js"></script>
  <script>
    System.import('app')
      .catch(console.error.bind(console));
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <app>loading...</app>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess you need

```
{{people?.totalrecords}}
```

to make it work.

You fetch the data before Angular renders the view, but the response probably arrives afterwards.

With `?.` angular doesn't evaluate `.totalrecords` while `people` is null.

Comment: thanks! so I must use for security always ? in my templates? what about when i have just not an value , can i use  {{?totalrecords}}  , thanks!

Comment: When `people` is `undefined` or `null` `people.totalrecords` throws because `null` doesn't have a `totalrecords` property. You only need `?.` when the part before it can become `undefined` or `null`. If you assign an initial value to `people` (for example in the constructor) you don't need `.?`. Otherwise `people` is undefined until the value from the server arrives. `people?.totalrecords` is a short form of `people ? people.totalrecords : null`

Answer (score 27):

If you want to see json, you just need to do this:

```
people: {{people | json}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want something more elegant you can use the HTML `<pre>` Tag:

```
<pre> {{people | json}} </pre>
```